# Objective-C framework BJImageCropper Border corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-framework

I want to change the design for border corner of [BJImageCropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper) like  this [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCMV8.png), can anyone help me on this ?

Currently I am using this code for initialize BJImageCropper :

```
self.imageCropper = [[BJImageCropper alloc] initWithImage:self.image andMaxSize:CGSizeMake(750,350)];

        self.imageCropper.center = self.cropView.center;
        self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
        self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
        self.imageCropper.imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);

        [self.imageCropper addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"crop" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

If there is any other framwork for image cropping that has the border corner like the sample image ,that might help also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [BFCropInterface](https://github.com/johnomarkid/BFCropInterface), which is actually  modified version of **BJImageCropper**. You will get all delegate methods of **BJImageCropper** in [BFCropInterface](https://github.com/johnomarkid/BFCropInterface).
Replaced below portion in **BFCropInterface.m**

```
 UIImage *nodeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"node.png"];
    tlnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:nodeImage];
    trnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:nodeImage];
    blnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:nodeImage];
    brnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:nodeImage];
```

With This :

```
tlnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-left.png"]];
    trnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-right.png"]];
    blnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-left.png"]];
    brnode = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-right.png"]];
```

where **.png**s are something like [image: This]

And have implemented the framework in my code using :

```
[[BFCropInterface alloc]initWithFrame:self.cropView.bounds andImage:original nodeRadius:50];
```

increase  the value of `nodeRadius` to increase the size of corner image .